# Visual Studio 2015 IronPython

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, ironpython

So recently I've thought about trying IronPython. I've got my GUI configured, I got my .py file. I click Start in Visual Studio, and that thing pops up: The environment "Unknown Python 2.7 [...]". I have the environment in Solution Explorer set to the Unknown Python 2.7 and I have no idea how to change it. Installed 2.7, 3.5, IronPyhon 2.7 and refreshed them in Python Environments tab

Comment: A screenshot or full error messages would help make this easier to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the best approach to handle this is to right click "Python Environments" in Solution Explorer, then select "Add/remove environments" and change what you have added in there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project ->  Properties -> General -> Interpreter

Set the Interpreter to IronPython 2.7 (you may need to install it).

Answer (score 0):

May be you didn't install [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/download/) because I encounter with same problem and after installing IronPython and setting as default Interpreter as @Ski mentioned

Answer (score 0):

[image: Options to set default Python version in VS 2017]
you may need to restart the VS and try a new project for Python.